# Apache Axis2 localhost:8080/axis2 not working

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis

I am VERY new to apache/tomcat/axis. I already had apache/tomcat installed when I started to install axis2 following their tutorial. When I try to start the axis services I get this error:

```
[INFO] Listening on port 8080
[WARN] Attempt number 10 of 10 to reestalish connection listener org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.DefaultConnectionListener@19a029e due to failure 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.DefaultConnectionListener.run(DefaultConnectionListener.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
[INFO] Listening on port 8080
[ERROR] Terminating connection listener org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.DefaultConnectionListener@19a029e after 10retries in 0 seconds.
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.DefaultConnectionListener.run(DefaultConnectionListener.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
[INFO] [SimpleAxisServer] Started
[SimpleAxisServer] Started
```

So I found that if I changed the $AXIS2_HOME/conf/axis2.xml transport receiver port from 8080 to 8081 then the service would work. But every time I would broswer navigate to `http://localhost:8081` it would redirect to `localhost:8081/axis2/services` and I can't ever get to the nice little axis home page that I read I should be able to get to.

So further down the tutorial I created my axis2.war file and placed a copy in the tomcat/webapps folder. Restarted and all that but I'm still stuck with not getting the Axis2 home page?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You are having a conflict between the server axis and tomcat apache ports, that's because you are trying to start both servers on the same port.

To fix it you must build first .war of axis and run it as a servlet in tomcat's "webapps" folder to get that cute page you want, in the server of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download the Axis2.war file and put into the webapp folder of the tomcat server. Once start the tomcat server axis2 is also running on top of that.
Then you can access the URL : localhost:8080/axis2